# why does this geometry node tree not work if i make a nodegroup out of it?

Tags: geometry-nodes

This is a follow-up question to the great answer of quellenform here:

[Texture map to a beveled curve or path](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43146/texture-map-to-a-beveled-curve-or-path)

I only wanted to make a nodegroup out of it, then i created a plane, added a geometry nodes modifier like this:

[image]

[image]

and added the same curve + curve profile, but i got this:

[image]

why is it distorted? what am i missing? what am i making wrong?

Comment: Works for me fine (without distortions) ... https://imgur.com/3oQjr68

Comment: I can't check this at the moment unfortunately, but did you follow the notes? The whole thing only works in the *Face Corners* domain. You would have to pay attention to the *Group Output(s)*.

Comment: @vklidu: thank you for checking that

Comment: @quellenform: of course i didn't follow the notes and obviously i cannot read ‍♀️ sorry for that stupid question - that was the reason and thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node group you are using creates coordinates in *UV space* for the vertices of the faces (*Face Corners*) after the node `Curve to mesh` has created the mesh.

If you put this node tree into its own group, you would simply have to write the generated coordinates into the domain *Face Corners* for it to work properly.

The reason why *Face Corners* are used here instead of *Points* is because you are using closed curves (*cyclic splines*) as the profile for your mesh. Therefore the endpoint of the curve is always at the startpoint, which causes this strange distortion of the mapping where the points meet. On the other hand, if you recalculate the coordinates of the *Face Corners*, you get a homogeneous mapping even with a closed curve.

*PS: If you don't want to begrudge me the RP, then please delete the question ...I just didn't want to leave a question unanswered here.*